# update sqlite table with perl

Tags: perl, sqlite

i have the below perl code to update record on sqlite DB

```
my $database = 'dbi:SQLite:dbname=my_db.db'; #

my $dbh = DBI->connect($database,"","",{AutoCommit => 1}) || die "Cannot  

connect: $DBI::errstr";



  my $sql = "update  my_table set table_id=51853 where table_id like '%49805%'";

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

 $sth->execute();


  $sth->finish;




   $dbh->disconnect();
```

it seems the code works but  the update is not saved on the DB could someone help with this issue ?

Comment: Why did you use `prepare` and `execute` instead of `do`?

Comment: You should examine more of the return values. The only one you've got any error handling on is `connect()`.

Comment: Try changing your attribute field in the connect statement to { AutoCommit => 1, RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1} and see if any errors come up.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how many [rows](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#rows) were updated. Log into the database and try this query to see how many rows would be affected:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE table_id LIKE '%49805%';
```

Also, make sure that you are using the correct database.

Comment: the result of the select is one the same record 49805 not updated

Comment: What happened when you tried to warn out $sth->rows? Did it say any were updated?